# SQL: Help me optimize my SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, optimization

I'm looking to optimize my SQL.

My database schema is:

### HOMES

- home_id
- address
- city
- state
- zip
- primary_photo_group_id

### HOME_PHOTOS

- photo_id (primary key)
- home_id (home primary key)
- photo_group_id (a photo group is the same image, resize from thumbnail to large size)
- home_photo_type_id (the size of the image be it a thumbnail or a large size)
- photo_url_dir (the filesystem location where the photo is stored)

### Problem

It's very possible that a 'home' does not have a photo associated with the home. In that case, the `primary_photo_group_id` = 0`. Otherwise,`primary_photo_group_id` equals the group_id of the photo to use as the primary photo.

### Slow SQL (b/c of UNION)

```
SELECT  homes.home_id,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    photo_id,
    photo_url_dir
FROM homes, home_photos
WHERE homes.home_id = home_photos.home_id
AND primary_photo_group_id = home_photo_group_id
AND home_photo_type_id = 2

UNION

SELECT  homes.home_id,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    null,
    null
FROM homes
WHERE primary_photo_group_id = 0
```

### What I would like to do

I would like to get rid of the UNION since I'm having to search back over the entire table 2x.  How can I get rid of the UNION since I need to check for the case where primary_photo_group_id = 0 and if it's not equal to 0, then query the `home_photos` table

### Here is the pseudo code that needs to happen

```
SELECT  homes.home_id,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    photo_id,  (include only if primary_photo_group_id != 0)
    photo_url_dir  (include only if primary_photo_group_id != 0)
FROM homes,
    home_photos (include only if primary_photo_group_id != 0)
WHERE 
    primary_photo_group_id = 0
ELSE
    homes.home_id = home_photos.home_id
        AND primary_photo_group_id = home_photo_group_id
        AND home_photo_type_id = 2
```

Comment: You're saying that it's slow "because of UNION".  Is that really true?  If you run either part of the query by itself, is it much faster?

Comment: Not homework. When I run EXPLAIN, it indicates that the the second query (after the UNION) is having to do an entire table scan. Whereas the first query only has to do a ref scan - which is MUCH faster

Comment: @Carl: Agreed. The UNION in this statement probably isn't the slow part.

Comment: @Jimmy8: It's not the UNION that's to blame for that, it's the lack of an index on primary_group_photo_id in the homes table.

Comment: homes should be fullscanned anyway in the first query. Having an index on primary_photo_group_id will speed up the second scan, while LEFT JOIN will make the query completely get rid of it.

Comment: @Quassnio - I've added an index to primary_photo_group_id.  Are you saying that I should NOT use the LEFT JOIN now?

Comment: @Jimmy8: no, I say just the opposite :) Use the LEFT JOIN and add an index on home_photos (home_id, home_photo_group_id, home_photo_type_id)

Comment: @Quassnoi, I should I use a LEFT JOIN or a LEFT OUTER JOIN. It seems like LEFT OUTER JOIN is the most appropriate and efficient. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jimmy8: they are complete synonyms. LEFT OUTER JOIN is pure syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you do not know about left outer join? Try:

```
SELECT  homes.home_id,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    photo_id
    photo_url_dir 
FROM homes h
left outer join home_photos hp on h.home_id = hp.home_id
    AND primary_photo_group_id = home_photo_group_id
    AND home_photo_type_id = 2
```

Comment: Should I use this, which does not use a CASE statement, or @Quassnoi?

Comment: The @Quassnoi version will give you better performance if you have a lot of primary_photo_group_id = 0.  If not that many then this code is simpler and more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  homes.home_id,
        address,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        photo_id,
        photo_url_dir
FROM    homes
LEFT JOIN
        home_photos
ON      home_photos.home_id = homes.home_id
        AND home_photo_group_id = CASE WHEN primary_photo_group_id = 0 THEN NULL ELSE primary_photo_group_id END
        AND home_photo_type_id = 2
```

Having a composite index on `home_photos (home_id, home_photo_group_id, home_photo_type_id)` will greatly improve this query.

Note that using `CASE` is slightly more efficient than left joining on `0`, even if there are no records with `home_photo_group_id = 0` in `home_photos`.

When `MySQL` sees a `JOIN` on `NULL` (which can yield nothing by definition), it won't even look into the joined table. When it joins on `0`, it still has to check the index and make sure no value exists.

This is not very much of a performance impact, but still can improve your query time by several percents, especially if you have a lot of `0`'s in `homes`.

See this entry in my blog for performance detail:

- [**Constant vs. NULL to mark missing values in OUTER JOINs**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/24/constant-vs-null-to-mark-missing-values-in-outer-joins/)

Also note that your tables are not in `2NF`.

Your `group_id` depends on `home_id`, and including it into `home_photos` is `2NF` violation.

It's not always bad, but it may be harder to manage.

Comment: Should I use this (which include a CASE statement) or @OrbMan, which does not?

Comment: @Jimmy8: this one is safer. But if you are absolutely sure you'll never have any records in home_photos with home_photo_group_id = 0, you may get rid of CASE just as well.

Comment: @Jimmy8: and note that using NULL instead of 0 to mark the absence of value is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If the second query is slower than the first, it's because you have an index on `{home_id, primary_photo_group_id}` (or perhaps just `{home_id}`), but not on `{primary_photo_group_id}` alone. You need an index on this column if you want to improve the performance of looking up on that column.

Comment: +1 This is what will speed your query, @Jimmy8, not eliminating the UNION - although you may want to do that for simplicity, too.  But for performance - the index is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Read up about [Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

```
 Select * from table_a, table_b
```

is a cross join - which you limit into an inner join with the where clauses.  Turn your queries into inner joins, then read up about outer joins.

**Edit**: I didn't just give you the answer, because I thought it was homework, but I still won't just give you the answer because outer joins are important enough to know about even if you're just writing SQL for a website.  you'll be a better person for learning it, and using this as an example.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Ritter, it appears I need to brush up on my inner and outer join statements :)